# Moble phone browser absolute bottom

Tags: html, css, mobile, css-position

I have an issue positioning text correctly with the particular offset from the bottom of the mobile browser. Here the CSS positioning it. This, obviously, being displayed correctly on any desktop browser (including low resolutions and corrected pixel ratio), but being displayed incorrectly on every mobile browser. It looks like mobile screen measurements take into account the potential menu size, but I am not sure.
How to fix that?

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
transform: translateY(-30px);
```

[image]

A live example is much more complicated, but this is the simplistic demonstration of the issue. On the desktop the text fits exactly into the black line. On a mobile phone, it moved up by 3-4 px

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
    scroll-snap-points-y: repeat(100vh);
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  }  
h2 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    font-size: 50px;
    clear: both;
  }
  section {
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    padding: 1rem;
    height: 100vh;
    scroll-snap-align: start;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    background: #EAB003 url('https://i.ibb.co/RTHZnxB/bgbg.png') no-repeat fixed bottom
  }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<section>
    <h2>Hello Kittie 1</h2>
</section>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Needless to add that 
position: absolute;
bottom: 30px;
does the same

Comment: Make a reproducible example, pls.

Comment: We need a code snippet, so we can see the problem. I guess by mobile browser you mean just the mobile viewport?

Comment: by mobile browser, I mean browser on the mobile phone. Mobile viewport is ok